# Aurelia project resulting in pickadate is not a function

Tags: jquery, aurelia, jspm, pickadate

I am getting the following error and I can't figure out how to fix it.
I've been more of a traditional JS developer and have been focusing exclusively on the backend lately.

I tried to manually load the specific JS file but it isn't working.
I am still getting an error.

**Current error is:**

```
aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [templating-resources] TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (c-field-date.js:80)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3246)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3496)
    at InputDate._attachPlugin (c-field-date.js:78)
    at InputDate.attached (c-field-date.js:51)
    at Controller.attached (aurelia-templating.js:3513)
    at View.attached (aurelia-templating.js:1558)
    at ViewSlot.add (aurelia-templating.js:1726)
    at eval (aurelia-templating.js:4534)
```

The hack I tried is as below, but it still fails:

```
$.getScript("/libs/pickadate.js-3.5.6/lib/picker.js", function(){


            //alert("Script loaded and executed.");
            // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script

        });
```

I heard someone mention that we may have a bug with JQuery being loaded twice but I'm not sure how to debug that.

The project is using `jspm` and `npm`.

Any ideas how to debug and/or fix this?

Note: This is not a duplicate. The other question does not relate to the error "pickadate is not a function"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time-Picker using jQuery in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285486/time-picker-using-jquery-in-aurelia)

Comment: @peinearydevelopment  Did you actually read the two questions carefully in order to compare them?

Comment: I did. That error usually occurs when jQuery isn't loaded at all. I pointed you to that question as it explains how to get this library to work with Aurelia, which is what you wanted. There is nothing in your question demonstrating where/how or even that you are loading jQuery not what you have tried regularly(only your hack which seemed to demonstrate a lack of knowledge as to how to get started using Aurelia and pickaday together). Just tried to point you in the right direction to get started. Sorry if it wasn't helpful.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thanks!  I'll have a look again in case it fixes these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that JQuery was being loaded twice. Removing the duplicate solved the problem.